# Plot title at bottom of plot using ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

In ggplot2, how to put the plot title at the bottom of the plot.

```
qplot(rnorm(100)) + ggtitle("My Title")
```

puts the title at middle and top of plot, while I want it to be at middle and **bottom** of the plot.

Comment: Another solution is to use instead of title the tag option, 
https://community.rstudio.com/t/figure-labels-or-captions-in-ggplot2/41067/3

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a solution using `grid.text`:

```
library("grid")
qplot(rnorm(100)) + theme(plot.margin=unit(c(0.5, 1, 2, 0.5), "lines"))
grid.text("My Title", x = unit(0.5, "npc"), y = unit(0, "npc"),
          vjust = -0.5, gp = gpar(cex=1.2))
```

[image: plot]

Comment: You have to open/close the device directly: `pdf("file.pdf"); print(qplot(...)); grid.text(...); dev.off()`

Answer (score 14):

With the dev version you can use the caption argument,

```
ggplot() + 
  labs(caption="Bottom Title") + 
  theme(plot.caption = element_text(hjust=0.5, size=rel(1.2)))
```

Alternatively, wrap the plot in grid.arrange(),

```
gridExtra::grid.arrange(ggplot(), bottom="Bottom Title")
```

[image]

Comment: I appreciated the first solution because it uses the ggplot's native functionality