# ggplot2 - how to place plot title at the bottom

Tags: r, ggplot2

A very simple question but it seems hard to find a suitable answer. How to place the plot title at the bottom. With the power of ggplot2 there should be some simple way to do this.

```
qplot(rnorm(100)) + ggtitle("My Title")
```

The question has been asked by others already. But the answers provided require a lot of manual adjustment and often painstaking. I don't want to manually adjust the `plot.title = element_text(vjust = -XX)` in the `theme()`. Any better way to do it?

[ggplot2-plot-title-at-bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30026887/ggplot2-plot-title-at-bottom-of-plot)

[Get help with ggplot2](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.ggplot2/8017)

Comment: Why do you call adding a single parameter "requiring a lot of manual adjustment and painstaking"? Have you encountered any unwanted behavior with linked solutions?

Comment: I'm plotting 3 individual plots and then combine them together using `grid.arrange`. Therefore, whatever position I adjust in the individual plots doesn't hold once they are placed together or even individual plot titles misplaced once you resize the plots for saving.

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing you want something along those lines,

[image]

```
plots <- lapply(1:3, function(ii) 
                        grobTree(rectGrob(gp=gpar(fill=ii,alpha=0.2)), 
                                 textGrob(paste0("plot", ii))))
titles <- lapply(1:3, function(ii) textGrob(paste0("title", ii)))
legend <- grobTree(rectGrob(gp=gpar(fill=4,alpha=0.2)), 
                                 textGrob("legend"))
line <- unit(1,"line")
null <- unit(1, "null")

layout <- matrix(c(1, 2, 7, 
                   1, 5, 7,
                   1, 3, 7,
                   4, 6, 7), ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)
grid.arrange(grobs = c(plots, titles, list(legend)), 
             layout_matrix = layout, 
             heights = unit.c(null, line, null, line))
```

Alternatively, wrap each plot in `arrangeGrob` and use the `bottom` argument for the title,

```
plots <- replicate(3, qplot(1,1), simplify=FALSE)
wrap <- mapply(arrangeGrob,plots, 
               bottom = paste("title", seq_along(plots)), 
               SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
grid.arrange(grobs=wrap, nrow=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. But how I can place my 3 ggplot objects inside the `grobTree`? Or, convert the ggplot objects to grob objects?

Comment: I used basic grobs for illustration, replace them with your actual plots.

Comment: I created lists of `plots`, `titles`, and `legend` and used the `grid.arrange` as you mentioned but got this error: Error in arrangeGrob(..., as.table = as.table, clip = clip, main = main,  : 
  input must be grobs!

Comment: After upgrading to latest R and gridExtra now I'm getting this error: Error in as.vector(x, mode) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'any'