# How to give title at the bottom of the plot using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am sorry for my basic question.

I would like to give the title at the bottom of the plot. How can I do that?

```
p1 <-ggplot(data=df, aes(x=variable, y=value, fill=variable)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + theme_bw() +
 theme(legend.position="none") + ylim(0,10) +  ggtitle("My Title") +
  labs(x="", y="y axis") + theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "black")) + theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size = 22,face="bold"))+ theme(plot.title=element_text(size=30,face="bold")) + theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size=18)) + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=22,face="bold"))  + scale_fill_manual(values = c("darkgreen","darkmagenta"))
```

Comment: An x-axis label or a main title placed at the bottom?

Comment: not x-axis label . Main title at the bottom.

Comment: The simple way is to just make a two-row x-axis label: `ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, disp)) + geom_point() + labs(x = expression(atop('x-axis label','the title')))`, though formatting it is hard.

Answer (score -1):

Using

```
+theme(plot.title = element_text(vjust = 10))
```

or take a look on this page:

[Plot title at bottom of plot using ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30026887/ggplot2-plot-title-at-bottom-of-plot)

Comment: This is a comment not an answer.