# Replace title to the bottom of the graph in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, title

In my head this is really a simple adjustment, but I can't find a simple argument to do it. I want to have the title not at the top, but at the bottom of this graph. Any line of text that I can use to this this quick and efficient?

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(20)
df <- data.frame(expl = rbinom(n=100, size = 1, prob=0.08),
             resp = sample(50:100, size = 100, replace  = T))

df$expl <- factor(df$expl, levels = c("1", "0"))

ggplot(df, aes(x = resp, alpha = factor(expl, labels = c("Condition 1", "Condition 2")))) +
  geom_histogram(fill = "#bebada", bins = 10) +
  labs(title = "I want this title to the bottom of the graph") +
  labs(alpha = "Condition") +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(0.5, 1))
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37676016/2461552) for some options like using `caption` instead of `title`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use, `grid.arrange()` from the library `gridExtra`.

```
p<-ggplot(df, aes(x = resp, alpha = factor(expl, labels = c("Condition 1", "Condition 2")))) +
  geom_histogram(fill = "#bebada", bins = 10) +
  labs(alpha = "Condition") +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(0.5, 1))

library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(p, bottom="I want this title to the bottom of the graph")
```

[image]

if you do not want to install the library, then just prefix `gridExtra::grid.arrange(p, bottom="I want this title to the bottom of the graph")`